# From a sequence of sets that transitions from all same value to completely random, how to know when it's made the switch?

Tags: random

Say I have a sequence that starts with:

H, H, H, H, H, H, H, H

Now each time I get another element one of two things can happen:

1. it exhibits the same amount of randomness as the previous element
   T, T, T, T, T, T, T, T
2. it exhibits more randomness than the previous element
   H, H, T, H, H, H, H, T

Assuming randomness is something that can be quantified, how do you analyze the sequence to determine the point (best approximation) at which it switches to completely random?

Note: in case this came out sounding like a homework problem (not sure it did) the context of this is using a pseudo random generator that seeds based on the current time in quick succession (very close time values) - they seem to generate sequences that are similar to each other and I wanted to test my theory (may very be wrong) that there's a minimum amount of time (greater than the smallest quantum in the target system) which must elapse from one run to the next in order to produce independently random results.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but: seed your random number generator only once.  Re-seeding won't make your samples any more random; it can actually make them *less* random, as you are observing.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good point for me to remember.  I sometimes get caught up writing the most to succinct code I can and skip over a detail like that...